# android_Get pictures from SDcard

Tags: java, android

Get pictures ​​path from SDcard.
My picture name is 01.jpg.

Make sure the picture is inside the SD card.

```
public boolean fileIsExists(){
    try{
        File f1 = new File("/sdcard/01.jpg");   
        f1 = new File("01.jpg");
        if(!f1.exists()){
            return true;
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
boolean file1 = fileIsExists();
```

If picture is inside the SD card,then put picture into imageview.

Error is in the following code

```
if (file1==true){
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);

    String myJpgPath = "/sdcard/01.jpg";
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 0;
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myJpgPath, options);//error here Cellphone can't run
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

[image]

Comment: which type of error getting ?

Comment: From cellphone:This application has stopped working.

Comment: String imageInSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/01.jpg";
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD);
        ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: try this code..you have getting error on Fetching Image From Sdcard becoz every device has different path .above code i think work on your project

Comment: Thank you very much.String imageInSD = ....+"/01.jpg";error:+"sdcard/01.jpg";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change +"sdcard/01.jpg"; to +"/01.jpg";

(And make sure Bitmap bitmap isn't repeat the local variables.)

```
if (file1==true){
    String myJpgPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/01.jpg";
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 0;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myJpgPath, options);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try  Following Code.

```
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/01.jpg");
ImageView mImgView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
mImgView1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: But my other app can run without any error.Only this program alert error.

Answer (score 0):

set your path like this:

```
String myJpgPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"folderName/01.jpg";
```

Comment: But my other app can run without any error.Only this program alert error.